# Таска по angulerjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Задачка вроде не сложная, но я больше по реакту, а таску надо решить очень срочно.
После 0 в конце строки обратно появляется 10 (в Title (10 символов), DisplayName (15 символов) и Category (6 символов)). а нужно чтобы уходило в отрицательные значения. то есть после 0 должна идти -1, -2, -3... и тд.
[задачка тут][1]

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/archivisions/pen/PeRdjB
```

```js
var app = angular.module("ngrepeatApp", []);

app.controller("ngrepeatCtrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.params = [
        {
            Title: "Title",
            Description: "Type Title Here",
            Value: "",
            MaxLength: 10
        },
        {
            Title: "DisplayName",
            Description: "Type Title Here",
            Value: "",
            MaxLength: 15
        },
        {
            Title: "Category",
            Description: "Type Category Here",
            Value: "",
            MaxLength: 6
        }
    ];

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        ol {
            margin: 20px 0;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        input.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
            border: 1px solid red
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="ngrepeatApp" ng-controller="ngrepeatCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 style="margin-top:60px; margin-bottom:20px">Таска по Angular+js</h1>
        <ol>
            <li>Под каждым полем ввода выводится строка "Available <i>n</i> symbols", где <i>n</i> - параметр <i>MaxLength</i> у каждого из объектов в массиве $scope.params.</li>
            <li>
                Вывести под каждым полем ввода вместо <i>n</i> не параметр <i>MaxLength</i>, а разницу между количеством введенных символов и <i>MaxLength</i> и,
                если разница отрицательная (т. е. введено больше, чем доступно), выделить эту строку красным цветом.
            </li>
            <li>Введенную строку обрезать до <i>MaxLength</i> нельзя.</li>
            <li>Форма должна иметь состояние $invalid, если какое-то из полей не заполнено или превышен лимит введенных символов, как и сейчас.</li>
        </ol>


        <form novalidate name="paramForm">
            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="p in params">
                <label>{{p.Title}}</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{p.Description}}" required ng-model="p.Value" maxlength="p.MaxLength.length*0" ng-maxlength="{{p.MaxLength}}">
                <small class="form-text text-muted" >Available <span>{{p.MaxLength - p.Value.length}}</span> symbols</small>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-disabled="paramForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: убери maxlength и ng-maxlength атрибуты

Comment: вот точно! СПС!

Comment: Только теперь кнопка остается валидной при отрицательных значениях... ((

Comment: как ее оставить не валидной при -1?

Comment: что можно сделать с ng-disabled="paramForm.$invalid = ..." или так нельзя?

Comment: можно добавить валидацию формы свою

Comment: подскажи как. а то совсем мозги уже не варят. в инете найти немогу...

Comment: там только добавить надо чтобы работало и при отрицательных значениях. а так все гуд!

Answer (score 1):

[Доработал.](https://codepen.io/archivisions/pen/PeRdjB)

Решил задачу по работе с `ng-disabled` в button (перевод кнопки в вид disabled при отрицательном значении в параметре MaxLength).

В массиве, `params` ищется элемент, в котором `value.length` больше `MaxLenght`, но find если что-то находит - возвращает этот элемент, поэтому впереди еще стоит !! дабы перевести в явное булево значение, то есть если что-то найдет, то будет true, если не найдет, то будет false и тогда будет выполнятся `paramForm.$invalid` для button, если и тут false то кнопка валидная.

```js
var app = angular.module("ngrepeatApp", []);

app.controller("ngrepeatCtrl", function ($scope) {
 $scope.isInvalid = function() {
    return !!$scope.params.find(i => (i.Value.length > i.MaxLength));
  }

    $scope.params = [

        {
            Title: "Title",
            Description: "Type Title Here",
            Value: "",
            MaxLength: 10
        },
        {
            Title: "DisplayName",
            Description: "Type Title Here",
            Value: "",
            MaxLength: 15
        },
        {
            Title: "Category",
            Description: "Type Category Here",
            Value: "",
            MaxLength: 6
        }

    ];

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        ol {
            margin: 20px 0;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        input.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
            border: 1px solid red
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="ngrepeatApp" ng-controller="ngrepeatCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 style="margin-top:60px; margin-bottom:20px">Таска по Angular+js</h1>
        <ol>
            <li>Под каждым полем ввода выводится строка "Available <i>n</i> symbols", где <i>n</i> - параметр <i>MaxLength</i> у каждого из объектов в массиве $scope.params.</li>
            <li>
                Вывести под каждым полем ввода вместо <i>n</i> не параметр <i>MaxLength</i>, а разницу между количеством введенных символов и <i>MaxLength</i> и,
                если разница отрицательная (т. е. введено больше, чем доступно), выделить эту строку красным цветом.
            </li>
            <li>Введенную строку обрезать до <i>MaxLength</i> нельзя.</li>
            <li>Форма должна иметь состояние $invalid, если какое-то из полей не заполнено или превышен лимит введенных символов, как и сейчас.</li>
        </ol>

        <form novalidate name="paramForm">
            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="p in params">
                <label>{{p.Title}}</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{p.Description}}" required ng-model="p.Value" ng-style="{'border-color' : p.Value.length <= p.MaxLength ? 'gray':'red'}">
                <small class="form-text  text-muted" >Available <span>{{p.MaxLength -  p.Value.length}}</span> symbols</small>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-disabled=" isInvalid() || paramForm.$invalid" >Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавь описание что и как в итоге сделал, чтобы стало понято в чем была проблема и как решилась

Comment: Добавил описание процесса

Comment: вместо `!!...find(...)` можно было использовать [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) он как раз возвращает `true` если есть хотя бы один элемент удовлетворяющий условию